# Regex to match key with optional quotes and optional separator

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to build a regex where it should be able to get all the values of the key mentioned in the log satisfying the following conditions

1. It can be either in single quote, double quote or no quote.
2. Key will be either followed by `: -`
3. Value can either be in single quote, double quote or no quote.

Here is the example I have tried out.

```
['"](?:accountNumber|subNo)['"][:-]\s*['"](\d+)['"]
```

This regex is finding out the `accountNumber` in the second part of the log

```
23:22:12.127 DEBUG Getting Service Details for: accountNumber-"525012078", subNo 5488870689 
23:22:12.403 INFO  /subscriptions, [{"accountNumber":"1233","subNo":"123","type":...}}]
```

Qn: Need to find out the `accountNumber` or `subNo` from the log, in both JSON format and statement log.

Comment: The second part of the second line of that log, is in JSON format. You don't parse that with a regex; you parse it with a JSON parser. Generally JSON cannot have single/no quotes - it must be double quotes. Various extensions on JSON allow otherwise; the log messages may be in that. Attempting to parse JSON with a regex is extremely complicated. After all, `"accountNumber"`, quotes and all, can be __inside__ another string literal.

Comment: How about something like `line = line.replaceAll(".*?accountNumber([^,]*).*", "$1").replaceAll("[^0-9a-z]", "");`? And what @rzwitserloot said as well, so maybe not that on the json one

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please try this - https://regex101.com/r/FWJmK0/1

Comment: Wasn't it supposed to be a Java regex?

Comment: @anubhava Do you have any suggestion or better approach?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(['"]|)\b(?:accountNumber|subNo)\1[:-]\s*(['"])(\d+)\2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QNQ3NX/2).

See the [Java code](https://ideone.com/oGhQxI):

```java
String s = "23:22:12.127 DEBUG Getting Service Details for: accountNumber-\"525012078\", subNo 5488870689 \n23:22:12.403 INFO  /subscriptions, [{\"accountNumber\":\"1233\",\"subscriptionNo\":\"123\",\"type\":...}}] ";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(['\"]|)\\b(?:accountNumber|subNo)\\1[:-]\\s*(['\"])(\\d+)\\2");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); 
}
```

*Details*:

- `(['"]|)\b(?:accountNumber|subNo)` - either `"` or `'` captured into Group 1  or an empty space + word boundary + `accountNumber` or `subNo`
- `\1` - Same value as in Group 1
- `[:-]` - a `:` or `-`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(['"])` - Group 2: a `'` or `"` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 3 (the result): one or more digits
- `\2` - same value as in Group 2.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, it can. The trick with the empty space matching will work here, right.

Comment: how do we replace the text in string, with the above example for java it's possible only to replace the accountNumber, `subNo` is not getting matched.

Comment: @Newbie Can you please clarify, if you have `Details for: accountNumber-"525012078", subNo 5488870689` as input, what do you want to obtain as a result?

Comment: I want to print out the log as accountNumber-*****, subNo-******
Just to clarify, there will be many matches in a single string. We need to mask all the group(3) value within the same match. @wiktor

Comment: @Newbie I believe you need `text.replaceAll("((['\"]|)\\b(?:accountNumber|subNo)\\2[:-]?\\s*(['\"]|))\\d+\\3", "$1******$3")`